# Hash Match Aggregate Cost

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization, hash

I'm trying to optimize a particular query 
I tried with hash tables but the performance didn't improved so much
I need to join the same table three times - pratichesteps - and then finally join with - pratiche -  table
This is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.PRATICHESTEPS.IDPraticaStep AS IDPraticaEsame,
                PRATICHESTEPS_3.IDPraticaStep   AS IDPraticaCatena,
                dbo.PRATICHE.IDSysStato         AS IDStatoCatena,
                dbo.PRATICHE.IDPraticaAccorpata,
                PRATICHESTEPS_3.IDAnalisiStep,
                dbo.PRATICHE.IDTipoAtto,
                PRATICHESTEPS_3.Accorpamento,
                dbo.PRATICHE.DataRegistrazione,
                PRATICHESTEPS_3.LastStep
FROM   dbo.PRATICHESTEPS
       INNER JOIN dbo.PRATICHESTEPS AS PRATICHESTEPS_1
         ON dbo.PRATICHESTEPS.IDPraticaCarico = PRATICHESTEPS_1.IDPraticaCarico
       INNER JOIN dbo.PRATICHESTEPS AS PRATICHESTEPS_2
         ON PRATICHESTEPS_1.IDPraticaStep = PRATICHESTEPS_2.IDPraticaStep
       INNER JOIN dbo.PRATICHESTEPS AS PRATICHESTEPS_3
         ON PRATICHESTEPS_2.IDPraticaCarico = PRATICHESTEPS_3.IDPraticaCarico
       INNER JOIN dbo.PRATICHE
         ON PRATICHESTEPS_3.IDPraticaStep = dbo.PRATICHE.IDPratica
```

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please improve readability of your code.

Comment: Did you check the query plan to see what's the bottleneck in your query? e.g. are the foreign key columns properly indexed?

Comment: The bottleneck is the hask match (aggregate) that costs 80%

Comment: All joins are on  non-clustered indexes

Comment: I'd like to use EXISTS but I can have results only on the first query

Comment: To explain better the query, I join the same table 4 times : the first time on idpraticacarico that ha an index and is pk with idpratichesteps. the third table pratichesteps is linked on idpratichesteps that is pk with idpraticacarico